# Multiprocessing infinitely slow when parameter beyond threshold

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

My script:

```py
import torch
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm

def simulate_condition(args):
    for i in range(args['n_steps']):
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_cores = mp.cpu_count()-2  # 22
    args = []
    with mp.Pool(num_cores) as pool:
        res = list(tqdm(pool.imap(proxy, args), desc="Simualate", total=len(args)))
```

The `simulate_condition` really just runs a for loop of a few random matrix simulations in pytorch like a markov chain and should scale linearly with `n_steps` .

Now I set the lengths to args to 40 and run this with different `n_steps`. The run times for the entire script are as follows:

| n_steps | time (seconds) |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 0.417 |
| 500 | 1.8668 |
| 1000 | 3.656 |
| 1500 | 5.603 |
| 2000 | 7.812 |
| 3000 | 12.116 |
| 4000 | NA |

At 4000 the script runs at least 1h, then I killed it. How is this possible? The processes are 100% independent. Running 22 processes takes no more than 6 out of 64GB Ram. Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Ryzen 5900X, Python 3.10.4. I can see all cores at 100% in `htop`.

What is the issue here? Why does it slow down so suddenly?

**TL;DR** Increasing for number of iterations within process, slows down the entire script completely.

**Edit:** changing from `tqdm(pool.imap)` to `pool.map` doesn't change anything.

**Edit 2:** Using `mp.get_context('spawn').Pool(num_cores)` on Linux doesn't make a difference.

**Edit 2:** On MacOS this works fine.

**Edit 3:** Using `numpy` solves the issue: When I replace the majority of computations from `torch` to `numpy`, it suddenly works normally. Still curious why it doesn't work with torch though.

Comment: Maybe using spawn? `with mp.Pool(num_cores) as pool:` -> `with mp.get_context('spawn').Pool(num_cores) as pool:`. This will create a fresh interpreter per process. No inheritance of variables. https://bugs.python.org/issue40379

Comment: What is your progress bar doing, i.e. where does it stall? How does it progress if you use `imap_unordered`? What happens if the number of submitted tasks is smaller?

Comment: @ReutSharabani thanks. I have to double check later, but that seems to solve it on my laptop

Comment: @ReutSharabani I tested it. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve it. The issue persists using `spawn`.

Comment: @Booboo thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't solve the issue. The way I understand it is that `imap_unordered` is superior to `imap` if I don't need order, which I don't, but the conditions are homogeneous in time, so it doesn't make much of a difference.